# How to use jQuery to get a certain value from a table?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following html for `Kendo.Grid`:

[image]

I have an aggregate function that built a footer row with the total of all the amounts in the rows: `Total: 91`

I need to get that text from the grid.

My Grid has a Click button event which triggers javascript `DeleteRecord` function:

```
function DeleteRecord(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var grid = $("#TicketReportPropertyGrid").getKendoGrid();
    var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
    dataItem.deleted = true;
    row.addClass('disabledGridRow');
    var totalArea = $('#TicketreportPropertyGrid table tfoot .k-footer-template td').eq(2).text();
    console.log(totalArea);
}
```

and when trying to `console.log(totalArea)`, it does not print anything into the console

How can I use `jQuery` to do that?

Comment: Id is `TicketreportPropertyGrid` - it is defined on the top of the image in `div` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#TicketReportPropertyGrid table tfoot .k-footer-template td').eq(2).text();
                                                  // third td ---^
                                               // get the innerText ---^
```

Comment: can I use some kind of selector so I do not need to rely on the constant number?

Comment: There is no id/class on any of those tds

Comment: I will try to add a class

Comment: If you are able to add a class to the td you want to find, that changes the context of this question entirely.  If you can do that it just becomes `$('.yourclass').text()`

Comment: Can I just use an attribute `style` for that footer template to get value, because, the footer will have only one column like that?

Comment: Your screen shot shows two with a style attribute.  And I would argue making a selector based on a style attribute and it's value is just as fragile as a positional operation like `eq(2)`

Comment: Actually, trying that example now and it does not work :(

Comment: Then please edit your question to include a text version of your html.  I can't prove/disprove that this logic works without transcribing your html from the picture to a fiddle.  And I'm not going to do that, :)

Comment: There was a typo in the id.  It was `TicketreportPropertyGrid`.  Fixed that.